# How configure Regex for words AND "e-mail"

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

My users has a TEXT field to inform some data. I utilize Regex to analyze each word of that text, using the following syntax:

```
 Dim UserInput as string = textbox.text.trim
 Dim AllWords as String() = Regex.Split(UserInput, "\W+")
```

Everything goes OK, but in words like "e-mail", the returned function does not considers it as a complete word (due to W+), but it considers that word as only "mail".

Since some users prefer to specify an actual MAIL (for send contracts in printed mode directly to their home addresses) but other prefer the contracts sent by email (via PDF), we are getting a lot of confusion in that specific case!

How can I set Regex to understand words like "e-mail" (I know it´s wrongly typed but some users write email this way!) with a hyphen as a whole word?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not clear about the question, can you provide a list of allowed and not allowed words for us to have a visual example?

Comment: "\W+" suggests to Regex ALL WORDS ONLY (and it´s true, I need ONLY words, not punctuation, numbers and so forth), but this function return "mail" to the word "e-mail" - that´s the main problem! Following this rule, any word with an hyphen won´t be accordingly treated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your regex to match words with hyphen in it. I wrote this in C# but you can easily convert it to VB.NET.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
string UserInput = "This is e-mail too";
string[] AllWords = Regex.Split(UserInput, @"[^-\w]+");
Console.WriteLine(AllWords.Length);
foreach (string x in AllWords)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Hakunamatata... Exactly what I need.